# How to bin age column for each category

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':np.random.choice( [12,15,17,95,13], 20),
    'category':np.random.choice(['A','B','C', 'D'], 20)
    })

Category Age
A        12
A        95
B        17
B        14
D        12
C        14
B        16
```

I want to bin the values of age, taking into account the category.
Suppose, I for category A, take its minimum and maximum value, and then find the bin.  How do I find bins for different category? I was using this for line for the whole column `bins = np.linspace(df[col_name].min(), df[col_name].max(), 11)`. And then grouping like this `grp = df.groupby(pd.cut(df[col_name], bins))`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @jezrael I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

A first approach could be:

```
def bin_age(sr):
    start = sr.min()
    stop = sr.max()
    num = 11
    bins = list(np.linspace(start, stop, num)) if len(sr) > 1 else [start]
    bins = [-np.inf] + bins + [np.inf]
    return pd.cut(sr, bins=bins, include_lowest=True)

df['Bins'] = df.groupby('Category')['Age'].apply(bin_age)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Category  Age           Bins
0        A   12   (-inf, 12.0]
1        A   95   (86.7, 95.0]
2        B   17   (16.7, 17.0]
3        B   14   (-inf, 14.0]
4        D   12  (11.999, inf]
5        C   14  (13.999, inf]
6        B   16   (15.8, 16.1]
```

Comment: bin_age requires an input. So I added df['Age'] and got `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: What do you mean? The input of `bin_age` is automatically given by `apply`. Do you need to add an argument to the function besides the group?